# UITableViewCells not removed when data is reloaded

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Figure 1.

[image]
Figure 2.
[image]

I've got a ViewController that displays a number of pages (indicated by the UIPageControl). Each page has a list of 4 tasks to be completed by the user, displayed in a UITableView. Each task in the list has a UISegmentedControl for the user to enter data for the task.

Tapping the page control increments or decrements the current page number, and triggers a `tableView.reloadData()` to display the current values of the tasks.

The tableView displays the correct data the first time the table view loads its data, shown in Figure 1. Incrementing/Decrementing the page control causes new cells to be created and placed *underneath* the previous cells, shown in Figure 2. The topmost cells in Figure 2 are the same cells in Figure 1. Since the original cells remain, it appears as though the ui is not updating when the page is changed.

The stack of cells grows by 1 level every time the page is changed.

Why aren't the old cells getting removed from the table view?

### code

```
class TheViewController : UIViewController {
    
    ...

    func displayPage(page : Int) {

        locationLabel.text = ...

        // refresh tasks array
        tasks = sortTasks()

        // refresh table
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
        
    @IBAction func pageControlValueChanged(sender: UIPageControl) {
        
        displayPage(pageControl.currentPage)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
        
        var cellId = task.pointnum == nil ? KCellIdentifierYesNo : kCellIdentifierLevel;
        
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as TaskTableViewCell
        
        cell.configureForTask(task)
       
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    // MARK: - Tasks
    
    func sortTasks() -> [Task] {
        
        let currentInspection = children[currentPage]
        
        return sortSet(currentInspection.tasks, onKey: "taskId", ascending: true) as [Task]
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you refresh the `tasks` array when the page control value changes?

Comment: That actually happens in `displayPage()` as well. Basically, the view control has a reference to a core data object, which has a relationship to `children` that represent the pages, and the children have a relationship to `Task` for the tasks. I will add it to the code

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that would cause cells to be put on top of each other -- I can't actually tell if that's what your view hierarchy is showing (could that  just be the different pages?). You said it doesn't look like the table is being updated -- what do you see? Does it not change when it should? You could put a log in the init method for your custom cell to see how many are being created, and whether more are created when you reload the data.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm so baffled! I updated the question to try to be more clear, and added another screenshot. There's actually no real "page". The page control just dictates which object in the children array we're taking the tasks from for the table data.

Comment: I'm guessing that you create a new UITableView every time you go to a "new page".

Comment: Set a breakpoint or use println to confirm that `tableView` in `displayPage` is the same instance as the tableView passed to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`